# Excel VSTO WorkbookNew event

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In one Excel Add-in project for Excel 2007 I need to check the event for the creation of a new workbook. I also needed to catch the Workbook_Open event which I did quite easily... On my research on the internet I found the following:

> Application.WorkbookOpen is raised when any workbook is opened. Excel
>   passes the Workbook that is opened as a parameter to this event. This
>   event is not raised when a new blank workbook is created. The
>   Application.WorkbookNew event is raised instead.

Unfortunately, I am unable so far to find the Application.WorkbookNew event... I am missing something?

After typing Application. the autocomplete provides a nice and long list of events for the Workbook (Open included), but I can't find the WorkbookNew event...

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `Application.NewWorkbook event`. [Here's the VBA reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ff837373). And here is a an [example in C#/VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.new%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Edit:

I cannot confirm the validity of this information, but I found the following explanation[(link)](http://www.databaseforum.info/8/697271.aspx):

> The NewWorkbook event is an application level event. Since there's
>   also a property of the same name, Intellisense won't show this to you
>   unless you explicitly cast the application object to the application
>   events:
>
> ```
>         ((Excel.AppEvents_Event)ThisApplication).NewWorkbook += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_NewWorkbookEventHandler(ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook);
> ```
>
> The event handler:
>
> ```
>     void ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb)
>     {
>         MessageBox.Show("New workbook" + Wb.Name);
>     }
> ```
>
> The procedure you were trying to work with is only valid in the
>   ThisWorkbook VBA project. It can't be used outside the immediate Excel
>   environment.