# VB.NET Excel VSTO NewWorkbook Event

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I'm creating an Excel add-in and need code to fire when a new workbook is created. There is an event in AppEvents called NewWorkbook that should fire, but Intellisense doesn't show it, and I can't get it to work using the object browser. I found several places online, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901146/excel-vsto-workbooknew-event), that explain the issue is because there is also a method with the same name so Intellisense can't distinguish the two and therefore provides no help. Unfortunately, every place I find it, including Microsoft's documentation, only has examples in C# and I can't figure out how to change it to work with VB.

(I did find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692802/excel-vsto-workbook-open-event-not-firing) while asking the question, but the title only references the workbook open event, not the new workbook event and I never found it in a full work day of searching.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use an online code translator to convert the C# into a close enough approximation of VB that I was able to get it to work.

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    AddHandler CType(Application, Excel.AppEvents_Event).NewWorkbook, AddressOf Me.ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
    MsgBox("New workbook" + Wb.Name)
End Sub
```

The way it works is to manually add an event handler as Application.NewWorkbook that points to a custom procedure that will handle the event.